# jQuery not finding a `span` element returned by Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, katex

I'm having trouble using jQuery to retrieve a HTML string retuned by Django. In a Django template I have the line

```
{{ generated_files.exercise_instructions.content | safe}}
```

which when expanded contains the string `2. Määritä luvun <span class="inline-math"> -6 </span> vastaluku.`, as shown in the picture below:

[image: Expanded JSON(?) string.]

I would like to be able to use KaTeX to render the contents of the span element as math, but

```
$(".inline-math").each(
        function(i, element) {
          console.log("Rivimatikkaa: " + element.innerHTML);
          katex.render(element.innerHTML,element);
        }
      );
```

does nothing towards this end. The span element of class `inline-math` is not detected by jQuery, as the `console.log(element.innerHTML)` does nothing, nor is the math rendered.

My question therefore is, how do I detect a string, that contains LaTeX returned by Django, in order to render it as math using KaTeX?

#### P.S.

As an interesting sidenote, here are pictures of the page source with and without the `safe` filter in the Django tag.

safety on

[image: Safe filter on.]

safety off

[image: Safe filter off.]

Notice the extra ampersands. That is the only difference, however. The string is not interpreted as HTML in either case.

Comment: This isn't related to django. If the source of your HTML (look in your browser developer tools) contains the span with class "inline-math", then jQuery `$(".inline-math")` should find it. How do you know it doesn't? There's no console output? set a breakpoint on your `katex` line and inspect what's `element`.

Comment: No console output whatsoever. I would disagree with this not being related to django, as the template tags definitely affect the form in which the string is returned. For example, omitting the `safe` filter messes up the `<` and `>` symbols in the string.

Comment: ok, but the javascript only interacts with the string once it's loaded in your browser. You said the output is correct (<span class="inline-math">-6</span>) when you look at it in your browser, so now it's not related to django anymore. And yes, marking something as "safe" is necessary to avoid escaping HTML.

Comment: I added a picture to show how the broser is interpreting the string.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the browser is *not* identifying that as HTML. Are you sure you used `safe`?

Comment: something wrong there because your browser seems to not see this as part of your DOM. Can you look at the raw source code instead? Not sure what I'm look at here.

Comment: In the source code it says `2. Määritä luvun &lt;span class="inline-math"&gt; -6 &lt;/span&gt;
vastaluku.` And I definitely used `safe`.

Comment: that means it wasn't rendered as `safe`. You're sure you still have `|safe` in your template?

Comment: and if you have, what is `generated_files.exercise_instructions.content`? How is this `content` defined?

Comment: Here's a JSffiddle link to the template: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=e5uPJUrEvg

Comment: The `generated_files.exercise_instructions.content` should be a string inside a JSON object.